# code not working in elgg?

Tags: php, elgg

```
    $widget = $vars['entity'];                            
    $container = $widget->getContainerEntity();                         
    $options = eligo_get_display_entities_options($widget);
```

This Is The Main Line Code That Is Not Work In My owner_block.php file.
and I don't know how to write that lines code in proper format

**elgg.2.2.1\mod\owner_followers_counter\views\default\profile\owner_block.php**

this code is not working in file name **owner_block.php** where I have inserted **owner_followers_counter** plugin.  When I insert this code in my owner_block.php file,  it's output is display most liked the post, but there is two line does not work properly, and I don't know how to format that.

where two lines are not working starting at `$container = $widget->getContainerEntity();`

```
                 $widget = $vars['entity'];                            
                 $container = $widget->getContainerEntity();    // problem here                     
                 $options =eligo_get_display_entities_options($widget); // and, problem is here

                $options['annotation_names'] = array('likes');

                if (elgg_instanceof($container, 'user') && $widget->my_likes !== 0) {
                  $options['annotation_owner_guids'] = $container->guid;
                }

                if (!elgg_instanceof($container, 'user') && !elgg_instanceof($container, 'group')) {
                  unset($options['container_guids']);
                }


                if ($widget->eligo_sortby == 'mostliked') {
                  $dbprefix = elgg_get_config('dbprefix');
                  $likes_metastring = get_metastring_id('likes');
                  $options['selects'] = array("(SELECT count(distinct l.id) FROM {$dbprefix}annotations l WHERE l.name_id = $likes_metastring AND l.entity_guid = e.guid) AS likes");

                  $options['order_by'] = 'likes ASC';
                  if ($widget->eligo_sortby_dir == 'desc') {
                    $options['order_by'] = 'likes DESC';
                  }
                }

                $content = elgg_list_entities_from_annotations($options);
```

Comment: I Will uses 3 Plugins, 1.owner_followers_counter, 2.Liked_Content,3.au_widget, I will get this code from liked_content and put into the owner_block.php so its not working

Comment: I will get code from liked_content Plugin file is elgg.2.2.1\mod\liked_content\views\default\widgets\liked_content\content.php and paste this code in to elgg.2.2.1\mod\profile\views\default\profile\owner_block.php

Some, Changes I have Do... Now

Comment: I want to display widget content into non-widget view file. but that procedure i don't know. pls. help me, get me some extension or information about that. in Elgg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**Ok, I Will Get Answer**

$user = elgg_get_page_owner_entity();
$user_guid = $user->guid;

$options['annotation_names'] = array('likes');
$options['annotation_owner_guids'] = $user_guid;

$dbprefix = elgg_get_config('dbprefix');
$likes_metastring = elgg_get_metastring_id('likes');
$options['selects'] = array("(SELECT count(distinct l.id) FROM {$dbprefix}annotations l WHERE l.name_id = $likes_metastring AND l.entity_guid = e.guid) AS likes");
$options['order_by'] = 'likes DESC';

$content = elgg_list_entities_from_annotations($options);
```